# Deserialize JSON data to datatable or multidimensional array

Tags: sql, json, serialization

I would deserialize (in VB.NET or C#)  a JSON file that i receive from URL in this data format

```
"{"350.20 AAA":
[],
"350.200 BBB":
[{"name":"arold","surname":"winter"},
{"name":"Rinald","surname":"Miki"},
],
"350.201 DRA":
[{"name":"Annie","surname":"List"},
{"name":"Rudolf","surname":"Mann"},
]
}"
```

I need to manage received data to write in oracle database.

I've tried with JSON.NET library

```
Dim table = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Dictionary(Of String, 
DataTable))(json_result).Values.SingleOrDefault()
```

where "json_result" is the string obtained from URL.

but it runs only if JSON file contains one record of Level 1 (es. "350.200 BBB") with corrispondant nested records.

Record at level 1 may be empty.

How can i approach to this problem ?

Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try adding the following Class:

```
Public Class Person
    Public name
    Public surname
End Class
```

Then using the following line to get an Object:

```
Dim jsonThingy As Object = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Dictionary(Of String, List(Of Person)))(json_result)
```

This will let you access the Object:

```
Dim personListA = jsonThingy("350.20 AAA")
Dim personListB = jsonThingy("350.200 BBB")
Dim personListC = jsonThingy("350.201 DRA")

Dim FirstBPerson
If personListB.Count > 0 Then
    FirstBPerson = personListB(0)
    Dim name = FirstBPerson.name
End If
```

`personListA` will have no objects in the list, so it will have a `Count` of 0.

If you do it this way, you are basically storing the values of `"name"` and `"surname"` in `Person` objects that are held in `List` objects.  This might not be desired depending on what you're doing, but hopefully it can help you see some of the possibilities if you don't want to store the data in objects.